# Extract nested JSON which have the same value for a specific key

Tags: json, python-3.x

In the following JSON, I want to extract a list of all the nested JSON objects (nested dictionaries) which have the same value for the `account_id` key.

```
data =
 [
    {
        "index": 1,
        "timestamp": 1637165214.7020836,
        "transactions": []
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "timestamp": 1489565214.7018296,
        "transactions": [
            {
                "account_id": "12",
                "device_id": "42",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 3,
        "timestamp": 1644585214.7012236,
        "transactions": [
            {
                "account_id": "13",
                "device_id": "43",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 4,
        "timestamp": 1644752214.7012756,
        "transactions": [
            {
                "account_id": "13",
                "device_id": "44",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For the above example, I expect to get the following:

```
 [
    {
        "index": 3,
        "timestamp": 1644585214.7012236,
        "transactions": [
            {
                "account_id": "13",
                "device_id": "43",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 4,
        "timestamp": 1644752214.7012756,
        "transactions": [
            {
                "account_id": "13",
                "device_id": "44",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Tried iterating over each dictionary but failed to get the desired outcome:

```
l = []
for entry in data:
    l = l + entry['transactions']

print(transaction['ticket_id' for transaction in l if 'ticket_id' in transaction]) # which only lists all the ticket id values
```

Surely there must be an 'easy' way, perhaps via the json module?

H

Comment: You will have to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Serge you are right. I added my code attempts.

Comment: what if there are different multiple entries with same account id...e.g two with id 13 and two with id 15 ?

Comment: @sandeep.kgp Haven't considered such a case. You can ignore it or you could display all entries where they have more than one same 'ticket_id'. The above is just an example on finding nested JSON entries with the same key value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in data:
    if not len(d['transactions']):
        continue
    acc_id=d['transactions'][0]['account_id']
    if acc_id in group_by_id:
        group_by_id[acc_id].append(d)
    else:
        group_by_id[acc_id]=[d]
print(group_by_id)
```

this would group every entry according to their `account_id`. Rest you can process according to the use case